# My RESTful services can't work

Tags: raspbian, node.js, mongodb

my RESTful services can't work after setting up my coding. Hardware I'm using is Raspberry PI. I created a folder called nodecellar which contains all my codes inside.

This is my server.js:

```
var express = require('express'),
    wine = require('./routes/wines');

var app = express();

app.configure(function () {
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));     /* 'default', 'short', 'tiny', 'dev' */
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
});


app.get('/wines', wine.findAll);
app.get('/wines/:id', wine.findById);
app.post('/wines', wine.addWine);
app.put('/wines/:id', wine.updateWine);
app.delete('/wines/:id', wine.deleteWine);

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Listening on port 3000...');
```

This is my package.json:

```
{
   "name": "wine-cellar",
   "description": "Wine Cellar Application",
   "version": "0.0.1",
   "private": true,
   "dependencies": {
       "express": "3.x"
   }
}
```

This my wines.js in subfolder:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var Server = mongo.Server, Db = mongo.Db, BSON = mongo.BSONPure;
var server = new Server('localhost', 27017, {auto_reconnect: true});
db = new Db('winedb', server);

db.open(function(err, db) {
   if(!err) {
      console.log("Connected to 'winedb' database");
      db.collection('wines', {strict:true}, function(err, collection) {
          if (err) {
              console.log("The 'wines' collection doesn't exist. Creating it with sample data...");
            populateDB();
          }
      });
    }
});

exports.findById = function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    console.log('Retrieving wine: ' + id);
    db.collection('wines', function(err, collection) {
        collection.findOne({'_id':new BSON.ObjectID(id)}, function(err, item) {
            res.send(item);
        });
    });
};

exports.findAll = function(req, res) {
    db.collection('wines', function(err, collection) {
        collection.find().toArray(function(err, items) {
            res.send(items);
        });
    });
};

exports.addWine = function(req, res) {
    var wine = req.body;
    console.log('Adding wine: ' + JSON.stringify(wine));
    db.collection('wines', function(err, collection) {
        collection.insert(wine, {safe:true}, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                   res.send({'error':'An error has occurred'});
            } else {
                   console.log('Success: ' + JSON.stringify(result[0]));
                   res.send(result[0]);
            }
        });
    });
}

exports.updateWine = function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    var wine = req.body;
    console.log('Updating wine: ' + id);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(wine));
    db.collection('wines', function(err, collection) {
         collection.update({'_id':new BSON.ObjectID(id)}, wine, {safe:true}, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                   console.log('Error updating wine: ' + err);
                   res.send({'error':'An error has occurred'});
            } else {
                   console.log('' + result + ' document(s) updated');
                   res.send(wine);
            }
         });
    });
}

exports.deleteWine = function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    console.log('Deleting wine: ' + id);
    db.collection('wines', function(err, collection) {
         collection.remove({'_id':new BSON.ObjectID(id)}, {safe:true}, function(err, result) {
             if (err) {
                        res.send({'error':'An error has occurred - ' + err});
             } else {
                        console.log('' + result + ' document(s) deleted');
                        res.send(req.body);
             }
         });
     });
}

var populateDB = function() {

    var wines = [{
              name: "CHATEAU DE SAINT COSME",
              year: "2009",
              grapes: "Grenache / Syrah",
              country: "France",
              region: "Southern Rhone",
              description: "The aromas of fruit and spice...",
              picture: "saint_cosme.jpg"
     },
     {
              name: "LAN RIOJA CRIANZA",
              year: "2006",
              grapes: "Tempranillo",
              country: "Spain",
              region: "Rioja",
              description: "A resurgence of interest in boutique vineyards...",
              picture: "lan_rioja.jpg"
     }];

     db.collection('wines', function(err, collection) {
          collection.insert(wines, {safe:true}, function(err, result) {});
          });

};
```

Comment: what error? Do you get it executing node or when a client hits the service? How are you hitting the service? What does hitting the service with curl -v ... tell you?

Comment: It stated that TypeError: Object function (req, res, next) { app.handle(req, res, next);} has no method 'configure', rob

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be some breaking changes in the versions 3.x and 4.x of express.

3.x used the

```
app.configure method
```

4.x now uses

```
app.set
```

A number of user have been hit by the same error message

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22202232/express-has-no-method-configure-error
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22265143/typeerror-object-function-req-res-next-app-handlereq-res-next-has

Comment: It displayed Cannot GET when starting up my RESTful services, rob

Comment: can you update your question with the exact output?

Comment: I can't get the exact output, rob